# Every combination of 2 strings in List Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I would like to combine every two strings in the list and return the list of combination using java8 streams:

```
List<String> list;
Stream.concat(list.stream(), list.stream())
                    .collect(toList());
```

However this code doesn't produce combinations but just elements of the lists. What am I doing wrong. I would also like this code to be parallelized so it can run on multiple cores

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to combine the strings in a combinatoric manner. Each string will be concatenated with each string in the list.

```
List<String> combinations =
    list.stream()
        .flatMap(str1 -> list.stream().map(str2 -> str1 + str2))
        .collect(toList());
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/Xs87bN)

To make the operations parallel, swap out `.stream()` for `.parallelStream()`. Depending on your input size, this may make the operation slower or faster.